# Angular : How to copy one array to another?

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm setting one array equalls to another

```
        orders = [
           {
            'id': PROCESSING,
            'displayName': 'Processing'
           },
           {
            'id': SHIPPED,
            'displayName': 'Shipped'
           }
        ];

        cloneOrders = [];

setOrders() {
        this.orders.forEach((order: any) => {
                this.cloneOrders = order;
        });
    }
```

But when I try to get values of 'cloneOrders' in another funtion it return an empty array

```
getOrders(status, minutes) {
        this.cloneOrders .forEach((order: any) => {
                console.log(order);
        });
    }
```

Both functions are in a same component. Please help me how to resolve this thanks.

Comment: You ought to be pushing them into an array: `this.cloneOrders.push(order);`. Make sure `cloneOrders` is initialized.

Comment: The `setOrders` method loops through the `orders` array and assign current iteration item to `cloneOrders` array. So when the function returned, you'll have the last item of `orders` stored in `cloneOrders` not the complete array.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try like this

```
setOrders() {
        this.cloneOrders= [...this.orders];
    }
```

Happy coding !!

Answer (score 2):

You need .push inorder to add items to the array,

```
this.orders.forEach((order: any) => {
       this.cloneOrders.push(order);
 });
```

better way to do that with ES6 using spread operator,

```
setOrders() {
        this.cloneOrders= [...this.orders];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do deep cloning -

```
let cloned = this.cloneOrders.map(x => Object.assign({}, x));
```

Answer (score 0):

you are assigning every time new object from `orders`  to `cloneOrders`, you need to push that `orders` in `cloneOrders`

```
setOrders() {
        this.orders.forEach((order: any) => {
                this.cloneOrders.push(order);
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

we can do using ES6 using spread operator

```
orders = [
 {'id': PROCESSING,'displayName': 'Processing'},
 {'id': SHIPPED,'displayName': 'Shipped'}
];

cloneOrders = [];

setOrders(){
  this.cloneOrders= [...this.orders];
}
```